# Duplicate login choices on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, login-screen, credentials

My windows 10 machine has exactly one non-builtin user, myself, an Administrator. I use a PIN to log in to the machine. Since I am the only user, and the only person with access to the machine, I tried to remove the PIN requirement. This resulted in the following behavior on reboot:

A login screen appeared telling me that the user name or password is incorrect. I note at this point that the user name displayed matches my account, but my picture is missing.
I click OK.
Now I have two login choices on the lower left side of my screen: one with my picture, one without, but with the same name.
I click on the login choice with my picture, and I am prompted for my PIN and can log in successfully.
I would prefer to be automatically logged into my machine on bootup, but at least would like to dispose of the extra step (1, above) if I cannot remove the PIN.

I have tried to research fixes, but most instructions I have seen are either grossly out of date or completely incorrect. And I apologize if this question is overly simplistic, or posted somewhere inappropriately, but I would love to be rid of this inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computer needs a PIN or a Password, or both.

Start, Settings, Accounts, Sign in Options and uncheck the option to restrict to Windows Hello.

Then when you restart, you should have the options for Windows Hello, PIN and Password. Choose Password.

Then if you wish to, you can remove the Password. I do not but it can be done.

Also if you have the password option, you can remove the PIN altogether.

Screen Shot here.

[image: Log in options]